# Perl/awk/sed Program to convert rows to columns between identifiers

Tags: perl, awk, sed

**My Input File Format:**

```
.set ABC
col2=123
col3=xyz
col4=bcd
col5=efg

.set prs
col3=456
col5=kda
```

**My output format:**

```
ABC~123~xyz~bcd~efg
prs~~456~~kda
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jatne. I worked. Would be great if you can help me in getting the following output:

Comment: `Same input but little modified output` How will someone new to this post understand your question?

Comment: @Tiago I doubt the OP really cares for longevity or helpfulness of the question in the long run, they did get their code for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{printf (/^\.set/?RS:"~")"%s",$0} END {print ""}' file

.set ABC~col2=123~col3=xyz
.set prs~col2=456~col3=kda
```

If a blank line at the top of the output is a problem, do:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "%s"(/^\.set/?RS:"~"),a} {a=$0} END {print a}' file
.set ABC~col2=123~col3=xyz
.set prs~col2=456~col3=kda
```

`/^\.set/` does line start with `.set`?
`?RS` yes, use `RS` a new line
`:"~" no, use`~` as field separator.

So this is just a test in the formatting to see if you should use newline or `~`

---

Updated to get correct result after OP change requested output.

```
awk -F= 'NR>1{printf "%s"(/^\.set/?RS:"~"),a} {a=/^\.set/?$0:$2} END {print a}' file
.set ABC~123~xyz
.set prs~456~kda
```

Comment: Explanation please :) Specifically this bit `(/^\.set/?RS:"~")` please.

Comment: @Jidder Its an `if` `else` test.  See my comment.

Comment: Forgot RS was a newline :( .Thanks!

Comment: @Jidder `RS` =  Record Selector.  I could have used "\n" instead.

Comment: I know it is, forgot/overlooked it being set to newline though.

Comment: @Jotne There is little change in my input. Some missing columns will be there in few line. These missing columns need to replaced with nulls.                                                                 Samle Input:
.set ABC
col2=123
col3=xyz
col4=efg
col5=hij

.set prs 
col3=kda 
col5=lmn

/*Note col2 and col4 are missing here. These need to be replaced by nulls*/

Comment: @lakki Updated your original post, since its not possible to see formatting int the comment field.

Comment: @lakki That would be a very different problems, and should be another post.

Answer (score 1):

Every set in separate line, delimited by `~`,

```
perl -pe 'chomp; s|^(?=\.set)|\n| or s|^|~|' file
```

output

```
.set ABC~col2=123~col3=xyz
.set prs~col2=456~col3=kda
```

If leading and trailing newline matters,

```
perl -nE 'chomp; s|^(?=\.set)|\n| or s|^|~| if $. >1;print}{say' file
```

*Update:*

```
perl -pe 'chomp; s|^(?=\.set)|\n| or s|^\w+=|~|' file
```

output

```
.set ABC~123~xyz
.set prs~456~kda
```

Comment: With this you get a blank line at the top and a missing return at the end.